# Sumas con String

Tags: java

Alguno sabe como podria realizar esta suma de String, explico:
La primera suma haciendo el casting a Integer me sale el valor de 25 eso esta bien, lo que me gustaria saber es como hacer para sumar con un resultado string sin realizar el casting ya que en lugar de sumar se concatena y me aparece 1015. Porfavor.

```
    String a = "10";
    String b = "15";

    int suma;
    String suma2;


    suma = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
    System.out.println("La suma es: " + Integer.toString(suma));

    suma2 = (a) + (b);
    System.out.println("La suma es: " + (suma2));
```

Comment: siempre vas a tener que convertir a un tipo de datos numericos, por una cuestion de polimorfismo. El metodo + realiza una u otra accion dependiendo del tipo de dato con los que opere. Entonces si el dato no es numero, el  metodo **+** concatena. Si el dato es numerico, opera matematicamente. No entiendo porque queres sumar strings sin cambiarle el tipo de dato...

Comment: ¿Sumar sin hacer el casting? Eso es imposible. Y ¿por qué motivo querrías hacer eso? Java no es PHP, ni Javascript y otros familiares.

Comment: Mi respuesta seria que no es viable otra forma esa es la razon de ser del **casting** ya que para poder sumar necesitas 2 numeros, puedes tomar varios caminos pero el mas optimo para mi es castear.

Comment: Es para una tarea, no sabia si había alguna manera de hacerlo por eso tenia la duda, muchas gracias.

Comment: @SantiagoLoachamin definitivamente tienes que hacer uso de Integer.parseInt(...), saludos.

Comment: No es necesario realizar el `casting` de forma directa, existen formas **nada eficientes** de lograr la suma de 2 o más valores tipo `String`. Sucede que es impráctico, pero si que puede ser un buen ejercicio para entender varios conceptos del lenguaje. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

El caso de la adición está bien explicado en la [Especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be
>   a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> In every case, the type of each of the operands of the binary -
>   operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive
>   numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> ---
>
> Si el tipo de cualquier operando de un operador + es String, entonces
>   la operación es la concatenación de cadenas.
>
> De lo contrario, el tipo de cada uno de los operandos del operador +
>   debe ser un tipo que sea convertible (§5.1.8) a un tipo numérico
>   primitivo, o se producirá un error en tiempo de compilación.
>
> En todos los casos, el tipo de cada uno de los operandos del operador
>   binario debe ser un tipo que sea convertible (§5.1.8) a un tipo
>   numérico primitivo, o se producirá un error en tiempo de compilación.

De lo dicho podemos concluir que:

- Si usas `+` con dos datos del tipo `String`, se produce una concatenación.
- Si usas `+` con un dato del tipo `String` y otro tipo numérico, ocurre una concatenación.
- Para sumar **matemáticamente** dos representaciones numéricas contenidas en datos del tipo String, debes primero convertirlos a un tipo numérico.

Comment: El operador + sobre un String y un dato numérico no produce error alguno, simplemente concatena y da como resultado un String. Incluso lo pone claramente la misma documentación que compartes: "If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation."

Comment: @E.Betanzos error mío al sacar las conclusiones. Ya he corregido. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: No te preocupes, a todos no pasa. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a lo que preguntas:

> lo que me gustaría saber es como hacer para sumar con un resultado
>   string sin realizar el casting ya que en lugar de sumar se concatena y
>   me aparece 1015.

**Para realizar la suma es esencial que los valores sea de tipo `int`, no es posible realizarlo con valores de tipo `String`**

Por lo tanto para la suma de dos variables en Java, es necesario realizar la conversión a int para poder realizar la suma, realizando un casting usando el método `Integer.parseInt(...)`:

```
String suma2;

String a = "10";
String b = "15";

suma2 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b));
System.out.println("La suma es: " + (suma2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mi gusto no tiene mucho sentido lo que estás haciendo, en el primer caso, puedes concatenar directamente el integer a un String sin necesidad de convertirlo a String, y en el segundo, al poner un String + String2 te va a concatenar sus valores sí o sí, tendrías que convertirlos a un valor numérico para poder hacer la suma...